# Android Loop beat with a Handler

Tags: android, handler, runnable

What I'm trying to understand is how to loop a simple beat in a given time frame using a `Handler` like a metronome. I've read a lot and saw a few things I can do but the best way is make a `Handler`, is this true? So after reading I tried something but I can't understand it exactly and it's not working right now.

**EDIT:**

This is what I have now, it's not crashing anymore but it isn't playing the sound like it should. What did I do wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mpBeat;

    private Handler playBeatHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable playBeatTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mpBeat.start();
            playBeatHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mpBeat = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beat);
        playBeatHandler.postDelayed(playBeatTask, 500);        
    }
}
```

Comment: what errors?  provide full logcat log...

Comment: Put `field = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beat)` after super.onCreate in onCreate. ... Before this activity is not fully created

Comment: Okay, that's what I did but it's not playing the beat right now. But it's not crashing anymore! But why doesn't it play the sound?

Comment: i didn't use MediaPlayer in my apps but ... i think that you forgot about `prepare()` method before `start()` try to add in your `run()` `mp.stop();mp.prepare();mp.start();` instead only `mp.start()`edit: remeber , there is no sound on emulator

Comment: Is there really no sound on the emulator? Haha then it's already working! Lol I just wasted one hour of my time playing with the code and the emulator. I'm going to try it on my phone now ;) It should work as I don't get logcat errors anymore!

Comment: Remember that this will not give you any sort of realtime accuracy. First of all, any delays in the media player will propagate into your loop, and neither does the handler give you any real guarantees on when the next beat will be played, except that it will be delayed with at least 500 ms. :-)

Comment: I've done it now with AudioTrack and it's verry accurate. The max delay I saw is around 0.2-0.5 BPM so it's as accurate as a real metronome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came across and what helped me a lot to build a steady beat!

http://code.google.com/p/android-sleep-metronome/

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        playBeatHandler.postDelayed(playBeatTask, 0); // now works       
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. See my logcat in the main post with the error.